# viewWillAppear is not calling up in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I created three view controllers named `A`, `B` and `C`.  `C` view controller is a sub view to `B` view controller and while executing `A`'s View is pushed to `B`. `C`'s View Controller delegate method `viewWillAppear` is not calling up.

Comment: c view controller displayed or not ???

Comment: Please show the code where you are adding C as a "sub view" to B. If you don't also add it as a child view controller, you won't get the viewWillAppear message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that C's view controller is a sub view to B.

I assume you're doing something like:

```
UIViewController *viewControllerB = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *viewControllerC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

//add C's view to B
[[viewControllerB view] addSubview:[viewControllerC view]];
```

If so, then you need to add viewController C as a child viewController of B.

```
//you need to set C to be a child view controller of B
[viewControllerB addChildViewController:viewControllerC];
```

This should make sure that the appropriate viewWill/viewDid methods are called correctly.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is with the IOS version.**

While adding the another view controller's view(viewControllerC.view) as a sub view to existing view controller(viewControllerB), `viewWillAppear:()` and `viewDidAppear:()` of viewControllerC **won't fire in ios 5.0 earlier versions**. If You need to call, then manually call this methods by checking the device ios version.

You can check the ios version and manually call the delegate methods like this...

```
 [viewControllerB addSubview:viewControllerC.view];
 if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion doubleValue] < 5.0) 
    {
        [viewControllerC viewWillAppear:YES];
        [viewControllerC viewDidAppear:YES];
    }
```